# C# Static vs enum for readonly variables

Tags: c#, static, enums

Say for instance you have the following class:

```
    public static class TimeType
{
    public static String DAY = "Day";
    public static String WEEK = "week";
    public static String MONTH = "month";
    public static String YEAR = "year";
}
```

Now when programming you would be able to access or these variables.

My question is would it be better to have them as an `Enum`?

The way i want to use these variables is as such:

```
    private DateTimeIntervalType GetIntervalType()
    {

        switch (TimeType)
        {
            case "week":
                return DateTimeIntervalType.Weeks;
            case "month":
                return DateTimeIntervalType.Months;
            case "year":
                return DateTimeIntervalType.Years;
            default:
                return DateTimeIntervalType.Days;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This type of data makes sense to use an `enum` for. I'd structure your `enum` in the following way though:

```
public enum DateTimeIntervalType
{
    None = 0, // this is a sensible default so you always have to define which
    Days = 1,
    Weeks = 2, // all are numbered so any changes don't rely on order of enum
    Months = 3,
    Years = 4
}
```

Then instead of your switch statement you can use:

```
var interval = (DateTimeIntervalType)Enum.Parse(
                    typeof(DateTimeIntervalType), 
                    text);
```

Then you can use your `enum` as usual:

```
if (someEnumValue == DateTimeIntervalType.Weeks)
{
    // do something
}
```

and

```
switch(someEnumValue)
{
    case DateTimeIntervalType.Days:
        // something
        break;
    case DateTimeIntervalType.Weeks:
        // something
        break;
}
```

Comment: The standard is not to use plural for enums. Use only the plural if the enum has the ``Flag`` attribute.

Comment: how do i get the value of the Enum once im in the switch? if it is just numbers

Comment: @MarcRasmussen I don't understand your question I'm afraid - `interval` which I have written there is the `enum` value based on the input of `text`.

Comment: @dav_i say for instance i want to use the above example in a switch with the int value of the day, week, month, year how would that switch look?

Answer (score 5):

Don't be afraid to create a custom type.

You could go with something like this:

```
// omitted error-/equality checking for brevity
public sealed class TimeType
{
    private static Dictionary<string, TimeType> _dic = new Dictionary<string, TimeType>();

    public static TimeType DAY   = new TimeType("Day", DateTimeIntervalType.Days);
    public static TimeType WEEK  = new TimeType("week", DateTimeIntervalType.Weeks);
    public static TimeType MONTH = new TimeType("month", DateTimeIntervalType.Months);
    public static TimeType YEAR  = new TimeType("year", DateTimeIntervalType.Years);

    public string Name { get; private set; }
    public DateTimeIntervalType Type { get; private set; }

    private TimeType(string name, DateTimeIntervalType type)
    {
        Name = name;
        Type = type;
        _dic[name] = this;
    }

    public static TimeType GetByName(string name)
    {
        return _dic[name];
    }

    public static IEnumerable<TimeType> All()
    {
        return _dic.Values;
    }
}
```

and use this type like a enum, but it's more powerful (no need for a switch anymore):

```
// looks like a enum
var day = TimeType.DAY;

// Get the DateTimeIntervalType directly
DateTimeIntervalType day_interval = day.Type;

// Get the correct TimeType by a string
var month = TimeType.GetByName("Day");

// Get all TimeTypes
var allTypes = TimeType.All();
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have an enumeration, use an enum structure.
If you want to have a value accesible from anywhere in your code that belongs inside of a specific class, then use static.

But if all you want is a value that cannot change, you may consider using a "const".

As commented by dav_i, in this case you are better of using an enum.

Answer (score 1):

`Enum` is just something like an Alias for a numeric value.
So if you want to have `strings` as you have them in your question, than enums are not the right thing for you.

to get the names from enums, you then have to use `Reflection`, and Reflection is not the fastest way to do that.

Answer (score 1):

I guess using `enum` is better since the datatype of the flag does not matter if it was string or integer. also `enums` is a very meaning full way to group flags together.